# Error message when attempting to use built in follow

Tags: facebook-opengraph, built-in

When attempting to publish a follow against a "profile", we always get the following message:

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Subscribee must be a user","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was because 3rd party ids are unique per user per app and we'd accidentally put one belonging to a different app to the one we were using in the page.